# Why do I keep getting "Unexpected EOF" in this bash script?

Tags: bash

I've written a bash script, and keep getting an "Unexpected EOF" error. I cannot find the issue in it. Could anyone point me to the right direction please. Any tips on how I can make it better would also be appreciated.

[Picture of the Error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6kaE.png)

And here is the actual script

```
figlet -ctf slant "3-Way-Riddles"
toilet -f term -F border --gay "Remember, all the questions have a \"ONE WORD\" answer!!!"

read -p "Please press the [Enter] key to continue: " 

read -p "Player One, please enter your name: " playerOne
read -p "Player Two, please enter your name: " playerTwo

one="0"
two="0"

function playerName() {
    read -p "Who is answering these questions? " name
        if [[ "${name,,}" != "${playerOne,,}" && "${name,,}" != "${playerTwo,,}" ]] ; then
            echo -e "Wrong name input, please enter your name again.\n"
            playerName
    fi
}

function points() {
    if [ "$name" = "$playerOne" ] ; then
            one=$((one+1))
            return $one
    else
        two=$((two+1))
        return $two
    fi
}

function echoPoints() {
    echo -e "$playerOne has $one points\n$playerTwo has $two points"
}

function progress() {
    if [ "$one" -gt "$two" ] ; then
            echo Winner is \$playerOne with \$one points.
            exit 0
    elif [ "$one" -lt "$two" ] ; then
        echo Winner is \$playerTwo with \$two points.
        exit 0
    else
        questions ~/TechnicalWritting/Random.txt
    fi
}

function questions() {
    line="$(wc -l $1 | awk '{print $1}')"
    for (( x = 1 ; x <= 2 ; x++ )) ; do
        for (( i = 1 ; i <= "$line" ; i++ )) ; do
            read -p "$(head -$i $1 | tail -1 | awk -F _ '{print $1}')" ans
            if [ "$ans" = "" ] ; then
                echo 2&1 Sorry, wrong answer.
            elif [ "$ans" = "$(head -$i $1 | tail -1 | awk -F _ '{ print $2 }'" ] ; then
                echo Good job random fella.
                points
            else
                echo 2&1 Sorry, wrong answer.
            fi
        done
    done
}

questions ~/TechnicalWritting/Math.txt
questions ~/TechnicalWritting/Logic.txt
questions ~/TechnicalWritting/Funny.txt
progress
```

Comment: I guess you could starting to debug this isolating the problem. For example, by commenting all lines but the first one. Check if works. Then uncommenting the second. And so on.

Comment: `echo 2&1` is incorrect; it runs `echo 2` in background, then tries to execute a command named `1`. If you're trying to print a message to stderr, you want `echo message1>&2`. Also, `echo Winner is \$playerOne with \$one points.` literally prints `Winner is \$playerOne with \$one points.`; it doesn't expand the variable names.

Comment: @KeithThompson I followed your suggestions, and still get the exact same error messages. Thanks for clearing those issues out for me tho.

Comment: thank you. I did not know figlet and toilet :)

Comment: You many want to read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) concerning how to iterate over the lines of a file.

Comment: [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is a useful tool to improve scripts. It shows the line of your syntax error, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

```
elif [ "$ans" = "$(head -$i $1 | tail -1 | awk -F _ '{ print $2 }'" ] ; then
```

`$()` is missing the closing `)`

```
elif [ "$ans" = "$(head -$i $1 | tail -1 | awk -F _ '{ print $2 }')" ] ; then
```

Recommendations: 1. I think it is a bash script. The first line should be

```
#! /bin/bash
```

2. Use an editor with syntax highlighting. I'm using kate, many other are available, too. Using kate, I straightforward found your syntax error.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been looking at it for like 4 hours and couldn't see it. Also I do have "#!/bin/bash -u", but just didn't put it in the questions.
I shall have a look at kate, cause using VIM and gedit did not help me see that at all.

Comment: You are welcome! Sometimes, I have tomatoes on my eyes, too, and I'm grateful to everyone showing me the hot point. :-) kate is cool. It has a lot of QT&KDE dependencies, but it is worth it. Syntax highlighting for bash is hidden a bit in menu, but kate automatically uses it if the script starts with `#! /bin/bash`. I'm not sure, if the script has to be executeable, too. There are only very few cases it does not show bash syntax correctly. (single `case` lines ending with `;;` immediatly followed by a new `case` line)